# How to convert a struct which has another struct in it in Golang?

Tags: go, struct, casting, type-conversion, type-assertion

I have a model like the following:

```
type TeamsKey struct {
    KeyData TeamsKeyData
    Fingerprint string
    Algorithm string
    Encoding string
    Usage string
}

type TeamsKeyData struct {
    KeyId string
    Key string
    Description string
    ExpiresAt string
    CreatedAt string
 }

type Key struct {
    KeyData     KeyData
    Fingerprint string
    Algorithm   string
    Encoding    string
    Usage       string
}

type KeyData struct {
    KeyId       string
    Key         string
    Description string
    ExpiresAt   string
    CreatedAt   string
}
```

I want to convert an instance of Key to TeamsKey. Although the underlying structure is same, I cannot convert it.

```
func main() {
    k := Key{}
    a := TeamsKey(k)
}
```

The error I got:

```
tmp/sandbox251934449/main.go:46:15: cannot convert k (type Key) to type TeamsKey
```

When I change `TeamsKeyData` to  `KeyData` in `TeamsKey` struct, I can convert the struct without problem.

The question is, why can't I convert the instances to each other even though the underlying structure is exactly the same?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not about the same overall structure, type conversion requires identical underlying types: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

Comment: Given this scenario, the best you can do is write a function that takes that type, creates the new one, assigns all the fields manually, then returns it. Or refactor so you don't have two identical structs... just the one.

Comment: @JimB so does it mean that even though the nested structs also have the same underlying structure (TeamsKeyData and KeyData), it is not possible to convert one struct to another because the TeamsKeyData and KeyData are not same types?

Comment: Yes. According to the language spec, you cannot convert them.

Comment: If you're comfortable with a dirty & inefficient hack, you could always encode to something like JSON or GOB and then decode into the target type.  But I have to agree with @RayfenWindspear here - the best solution would be to have one type rather than two identical types.

Answer (score 1):

When converting an item it is not enough for them to have identical layouts, they [need to have the same underlying type for all their fields](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

In this case the best you can do is to make a new struct of the type you want and fill out it's fields with data from the old struct.

I played around some with this, but I was not able to do better than that.

I assume that the two `KeyData` types need different method sets? If this is *not* the case, you should just use the same type both places.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert or assign variables of different types normal way. But if it's necessary and you are certain the strutures have the same underlying layout, you can omit compiler's guarantee and do it unsafe.

```
import "unsafe"
...
a := *((*TeamsKey)(unsafe.Pointer(&k)))
...
```

It's not recommended without serious reasons, you should well understand what you do.

Comment: I personally cannot condone suggesting someone bypassing the types who doesn't fully understand them.

Comment: So should I better delete the answer? But technically we can do.

Comment: Add some good warnings about how this isn't a good idea and I'll remove the downvote. The big problem is that this will probably cause random panics somewhere down the line. A seemingly benign change to one struct suddenly causing panics that would be hard to track down.

Comment: Or worse... consider this example, where there is no panic, no error, just a bad conversion. https://play.golang.org/p/IrBZUhhwE7